# Azure AD appending '#EXT#' to UserPrincipalName

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

When we create a user in Active Directory using Graph API, some characters are appended to the username (#EXT#). This makes impossible to edit the user in AD B2C's interface ([documented problem](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-limitations/)) or doing sign-in using ADAL 2.23 (Active Directory Authentication Library).

[image: AD B2C interface problem]

Particularly, there's an error (`unknown_user_type`) when we use `AcquireToken(username, password)` method. The error is the following:

[image: ADAL error]

Why is this happening? Is there any solution or workaround for this problem?.

Regards.

Comment: Is the user sourced from an external provider? AAD has appended a similar string to my Microsoft account connected to it. AAD itself would be unable to authenticate the user directly, it needs to redirect the user to log in at their provider.

Comment: @juunas yes, is because the Graph API is another app. Is there any workaround?

Comment: This is by design, it is mentioned in the B2C limitations and this field is actually the UPN, and shouldnt be displayed.

Comment: @MauricioUlloa I've edited the title to reflect that it is not the Azure AD Graph API that is adding the `#EXT#`, but Azure AD itself.

Answer (score 7):

Users that have `#EXT#` in their UserPrincipalName (UPN, also ambiguously referred to as "username" in several places) are typically users that have been sourced from other identity providers. This includes:

1. Regular directories: Users added with their Microsoft Account (MSA)
2. Regular directories: Users from other directories in Azure AD
3. B2C directories: Almost all B2C users have this

**Regular directories**

If your application is aware of the Azure AD directory the user are trying to sign in *to*, and you are using the tenant-specific endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain or ID>`, instead of the tenant-agnostic endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`, users in case (1) and (2) should be able to sign in with an application using ADAL. When signing in, they would use their regular usernames from MSA or their "home" directory.

Example: User `bob@contoso.com`, from directory `contoso`, is added as an external user in directory `fabrikam`. This results as a user in `fabrikam` with UPN `bob_contoso.com#EXT#@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`, but you don't have to worry about that. When they sign in to an application that trusts `https:/login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`, they simply sign in as `bob@contoso.com` and use their normal password from `contoso`.

**B2C directories**

Azure AD B2C-aware applications always work with a tenant-specific endpoint, but it's using the newer "v2" OAuth 2.0 endpoints:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain or ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain or ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Again--users will always sign in using their home identity provider.

IMPORTANT: Remember that Azure AD B2C is currently in *Preview* (as of March 2106).

**TL;DR**:

You should not actually have any scenario where you would want to change users' UserPrincipalName if it contains `#EXT#`, because this means this isn't actually the username they would type when signing in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is not when editing the UPN, is when editing any field or trying to sign-in using ADAL.

Comment: Which of the three cases above do you fit in? Are you following any of the existing samples, or did you start from scratch?

Comment: Our case is the 3rd one. Thanks!

Comment: @MauricioUlloa What version of ADAL are you trying to use? Can you edit your post to include the specific error message you're observing?

Comment: In my case, the users created a MS account before existence of Azure AD. Now, all users from newly directory `contoso` stays like `bob#EXT#@contoso.com` and I can't figure out how to convert them to internal users.