# Azure PowerShell Command: `Get-AzSubscription ...` - SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: AADSTS9002332

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I've some PowerShell Script on Configuring the Azure Key Vault, where I'm running each command one by one for observing the execution flow:

```
#Log into Azure
Add-AzAccount
```

**Result**:

[image]

```
#Select the correct subscription
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Test Subscription" | Select-AzSubscription
```

**Error**:

```
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Test Subscription" | Select-AzS …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: AADSTS9002332: Application '<some_Guid_id>'(Windows Azure Service Management API) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only. Please do not use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request.
```

I didn't get much details about above error for resolving the issue.

**Note**:

1. I'm the owner of my Azure Tenant/Subscription, logged in with the same account credentials in the Visual Studio code for executing the PowerShell Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the user principal name of the user you’re logging with the Azure PowerShell command, is ending with the external identity provider i.e., `gmail.com`.
If that user is the root user (Tenant Owner + Subscription Owner), then you cannot login with the `Add-AzAccount` because they are added as external users.

To login with that command, you have to add the user in that subscription and give the Global Administrator as Azure AD Role and required role in Subscription level such as Owner, Contributor etc.

Hence, this new user is part of your Azure Tenant Domain and UPN ends with the domain such as `onmicrosoft.com` or any other configured custom domain.

[image]

For more information on External Users, Guest Users, Tenant Domain users, Refer to this Similar issues on SO #[35727866](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733439) given by the user @*PhilippeSignoret* and MS Q&A #[81053](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/81053/user-principal-name-and-ext) by the user @*VasilMichev*.

Comment: Hey @DasariKamali, Thanks for your answer. I have seen this discussions recently and the same you have given. The issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

To log into Azure, I would suggest using:

**Connect-AzAccount**

- This will prompt you to open a browser and authenticate to your Azure tenant

To set the Azure subscription you want to work in:

**Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName 'paste-your-subscription-name-here'**

Comment: These commands worked but the commands given in the question worked for the course author in Pluralsight without any errors. So, what could be the cause of those errors to the command lets given in the question?

Comment: Hi Hey Hasher, I believe that Add-AzAccount is an alias for Connect-AzAccount. Both commands come from the AzAccounts PowerShell module. You could try get-command -module az.accounts to check what commands are included in the current version of the module on your computer. I have version 2.12.2 installed for the Az.Accounts module. I am not sure why Add-AzAccount is not working for you. I always use Connect-AzAccount.

Comment: I know there are some aliases of `Connect-AzAccount`. Could you confirm that you're logging with the Azure Tenant Owner credentials or credentials of an user created in your tenant-Subscription credentials.